# Integral solutions of $a^{2} + a = b^{3} + b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

Find all pairs of coprime positive integers $(a,b)$ such that 
$b<a$ and $a^2+a=b^3+b$

My approach:
$a(a+1)=b(b^2+1)$ so $a|(b^2+1)$ and $b|(a+1)$
Now after this I am not able to do anything.pls help.

Comment: I find $a=5,b=3$ as  a solution.  No others below $b=250$  I just put your equation into the quadratic formula and asked when $\sqrt{1+4b+4b^3}$ was an integer.

Comment: Could you please show how it will be an integer only at b=3?

Comment: No, I can't.  I just used a spreadsheet and copied down to check through $b=249$.  I found $a=b=0, a=b=1$ as well, but they fail $a \lt b$.  I suspect there are no more, but don't know that.  That is why I made it a comment.

Comment: [LMFDB entry](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/91/a/1) of this elliptic curve. Only integer solutions are $(a,b)\in\{(0,0),(1,1),(5,3)\}$.

Comment: Oopsie. Forgot about the negatives of those points. That is $(-1,0)$, $(-2,1)$ and $(-6,3)$. Anyway, when restricted to positive integers and $b<a$ the only solution is $(5,3)$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you already note, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime and
$$a(a+1)=a^2+a=b^3+b=b(b^2+1),$$
then it follows that $b$ divides $a+1$. Then $a=bc-1$ for some integer $c$, where $c>1$ because $a>b$. Then
$$b^3+b=a^2+a=(bc-1)^2+(bc-1)=c^2b^2-cb,$$
and since $b$ is positive we can divide both sides by $b$ and rearrange to get the quadratic
$$b^2-c^2b+c+1=0,\tag{1}$$
in $b$.
This shows that the integer $b$ is a root of a quadratic equation with discriminant
$$\Delta=(-c^2)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(c+1)=c^4-4c-4.$$
In particular this means $c^4-4c-4$ is a perfect square. Of course $c^4$ is itself a perfect square, and the previous one is
$$(c^2-1)^2=c^4-2c^2+1,$$
which shows that $-4c-4\leq-2c^2+1$, or equivalently
$$2c^2-4c-5\leq0.$$
A quick check shows that this implies $c<3$, so $c=2$. Then this plugging back into $(1)$ yields
$$b^2-4b+3=0,$$
and so either $b=1$ or $b=3$, corresponding to $a=1$ and $a=5$, respectively. Hence the only solution with $a>b$ is $(a,b)=(5,3)$.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's worth mentioning that the original equation does not a priori  imply that $b$ divides $a+1$, so this argument does not actually solve the problem.

Comment: The fact that $a \cdot b=c \cdot d$ with $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$ does not imply that $a$ must divide one of $c$ or $d$. Consider, for example, $6 \cdot 35 = 10 \cdot 21$.

Comment: The corresponding elliptic curve here has rank $1$ and I'm really not sure that a simple elementary argument will work.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice the original assumption that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. My mistake.

Comment: It is always nice to see proved by elementary means, a result that is usually proved with sophisticated means (in this case with elliptic curve arithmetic).